# Scheduled task only runs as expected if I run it once - never on its own (Azure mobile services)

Tags: azure, scheduler, azure-mobile-services

I am running a simple script in azure mobile services scheduler:

```
function warmup() {
    warmUpSite("http://safenoteit.ca/");
}

function warmUpSite(url) {
    console.info("warming up: " + url);

    var req = require('request');
    req.get({ url: url }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            console.info("hot hot hot! " + url);
        } else {
            console.error('error warming up ' + url + ': ' + error);
        }       
    });
}
```

This runs as expected when I manually run it (Run once button). However, despite scheduling it to run every 15 minutes, I don't see any console log messages coming from the script. Additionally, the portal tells me that the scheduler is enabled and running:

[image: scheduler screenshot]

Anyone else see this issue? The mobile service is running on basic tier and I have very little load on it. I don't see what could cause this issue, which makes the whole scheduler service useless.

UPDATE: Tried the same scheduled script on another mobile service, and everything works! Something's messed up with the mobile service itself. Talking to Microsoft support to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue only Microsoft can fix. They had to redeploy the mobile service.